# SWIFT - How to turn on GPS when using UIImagePickerController and how to retrieve that data later on

Tags: ios, swift, gps, geolocation

When printing out the following

'let metadata = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata] as NSDictionary'

I don't see GPS information. How do you properly get this data when taking pictures in Swift?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing... any clues?

Comment: Please file a bug report requesting this.